# Why Add Disjunction in VRP solver Not Working As Expected?

Tags: or-tools

*cross [posted](https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/9sWN8abtmxw/m/PmBM_Wc_AwAJ) from OR-tools google group*

I am working with a multi-vehicle VRP with due dates over 5 periods (ex. some nodes are due at time t=0, so I give them a penalty cost of 10000 and 1000 for all other nodes, etc. till period 4). Initially I followed the exact steps as laid out [here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/penalties) with "AddDisjunction" to set priorities for certain nodes, and so expected that the solution would always pick up more, rather than less, nodes. However, in my example code , you'll see that the solver is dropping multiple nodes with smaller demand and picking up nodes with larger demand instead. I came across this same issue when working on a single-vehicle problem, but I was able to use AddSoftSameVehicleConstraint as a workaround.

My code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GHYJbH_aKcCkfoYy_7fwqmnpIs_Nasrr?usp=sharing): I would direct you to the cell titled "Basic SVRP" onwards; the cells prior are for data generation. The most important thing in the output is that, all nodes starting with "a" or "b" are only of demand 1-2 units, while "c" and "d" are of demands between 4-8 units. Therefore, I should ideally see nodes of "a" and "b" only dropped as a last resort.

Any help here to rectify this would be greatly appreciated, happy to simplify/clarify where needed.

Comment: Please indicate when you are cross-posting from or-tools-discuss or github discussion.

Comment: Sorry! I have done so now.